# Conditionally decide which view controller to open after tab press

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

On tapping on a tab I want to navigate to either a LoginViewController  or ProfileViewController depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

How can I achieve this in swift , where do i place the logic for this?

At the momen the tab press just navigates to the login screen, but if they are logged in i dont want them to go to the login screen,  id rather it just went straight to the profile screen

Comment: ....and downvotes because???

Comment: By tab, do you mean a tab on the tabbar?
If so, create a subclass of UITabBarController and write your logic in there. Set the ProfileViewController as the viewController for the tab if the user has logged in, otherwise, set LoginViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you have and what you want to do this is what i propose to you.
Add `willAppear` function to the profileview and there check if there is a user logged in with a value that you would save with `userdefaults` and depends of what you will have you will navigate to the view that you have to go.

Comment: Whilst this did work, when i try  and dismiss the login screen (i.e dont want to log in right now) it closes,  displays the profile screen briefly then opens the login screen again...Idealy i think i need to intercept as soon as tab is pressed and navigate to the right VC

Comment: @raklos you can try to add your conditions inside willdisappear of the previous tab so it will be ready and don't show the profilview